# PHP monitor available bandwidth

Tags: php, performance, monitoring, ping, bandwidth

I'm creating a command line script in php that will use a lot of bandwidth so I want to monitor available bandwidth to balance the size of sending data. (Automatic TCP balancing it's not enough cause it can send a lot of data)

I'll be working under linux, I already use '/proc/meminfo' to monitor ram but I haven't found a general command(no external package) to monitor bandwidth.

I was thinking to monitor latency of a ping to google.com, but I'm not sure how to do it, any ideas?

Comment: What does the latency of a ping have to do with the bandwidth?

Comment: There are some apache modules dealing with bandwidth control, so if you use apache as your http server it might make sense to look into those.

Comment: If the bandwidth is full the ping won't arrive, or will be strongly delayed

Comment: But that a) does say nothing about the bandwidth but only if the network throughput is close to its limit and b) such a delay could have millons of other reasons and c) that actually depends on the network management of the system.

Comment: I know it's not the best measure but I couldn't figure out another way.
Apache modules are useless because is a server-side script that can run on his own

Comment: Then I'd say you have to use the systems own network interface management. You ran read quite a bunch of information alone from the `proc` pseudo file system. Also there are custom traffic shaping solutions. You can do all that from php, if you have to. But I'd say: first find a clean solution to get the information you are looking for, next think about using that from php.